# MediaWiki footer viewcount

Tags: php, footer, mediawiki

I'm using MediaWiki, wanna to show view count on foot.

My env:

MediaWiki 1.25.1

PHP 5.4.41

MySQL 5.5.43

Readed offical manual https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Footer but i dont know how to do.

It's say:

```
$wgHooks['SkinTemplateOutputPageBeforeExec'][] = 'lfTOSLink';
function lfTOSLink( $sk, &$tpl ) {
    $tpl->set( 'termsofservice', $sk->footerLink( 'termsofservice', 'termsofservicepage' ) );
    $tpl->data['footerlinks']['places'][] = 'termsofservice';
    return true;
}
```

how to change code of lfTOSLink to turn on viewcount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the hit counter was removed in MediaWiki 1.25, [Extension:HitCounters](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HitCounters) is now available to replace the core functionality, thanks to Mark A. Hershberger.

Comment: Sorry, I still like integrated function.

Answer (score 1):

Viewcount was removed in MediaWiki 1.25. See the documentation of [$wgDisableCounters](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDisableCounters) for details and alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I degrade version to 1.21.1

Page footer's view count is working fine.

Reinstall a new instance 1.21.1

Use [Maintenance scripts](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Maintenance_scripts) : [DumpBackup](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:DumpBackup.php) , [ImportDump](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportDump.php) , [ImportImages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportImages.php)

Succeed migrate data to 1.21.1 from 1.25.1

Comment: This does not seem like a good choice - you downgraded to a non-supported version. If you really have to, MediaWiki 1.23 would have been a better choice, as it's an LTS (until May 2017). Anyway, see my answer.

Comment: Thanks for suggest!  When i get a leisure, i'll upgrade it to 1.23.